# how to adjust group by when building R plotly trace loop

Tags: r, loops, group-by, plotly, trace

## how to re-group the data by using another attribute after using trace loop #for plotly in R

```
# Initialize empty plot
p <- plot_ly()

# Each task is a separate trace
# Each trace is essentially a thick line plot
# x-axis ticks are dates and handled automatically

for(i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)){
  p <- add_trace(p,
             x = c(df$Start[i], df$Start[i] + df$Duration[i]),  # x0, x1
             y = c(i, i),  # y0, y1
             mode = "lines",
             line = list(color = df$color[i], width = 20),
             showlegend = F,
             hoverinfo = "text",

             # Create custom hover text

             text = paste("Task: ", df$Task[i], "<br>",
                          "Duration: ", df$Duration[i], "days<br>",
                          "Resource: ", df$Resource[i]),

              evaluate = T  # needed to avoid lazy loading
  )
}
```

## Based on the above gantt chart R code, how to group data by "resource" as #another attribute after adding the trace loop. I would like to add legend #that not group by trace, or it will show all trace added in this loop. #Please advice. Thank you!